# main.cpp:10:17: error: expected expression

Tags: stdstring

```
std::string no_space(std::string x)
{
    
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    
    if (x[i] == '') {
      
      x.erase(x[i]);
      
    }
  }
  return x; 
}
```

I got an expected expression error. I am new to coding and do not know what this means. Please help.

Comment: On this line: `if (x[i] == '') {` - do you have a space between those single quotes? Or what are you comparing `x[i]` with?

Comment: Ah. I don't have a space. I am comparing on whether that particular indice in the string has a character or no character. Thanks for noticing this, and I feel stupid for not noticing something like this.

Comment: Well, your compiler pointed you to the exact location of the error (line#:character#); mine (Microsoft) just stated the line, but error description was better: `error C2137: empty character constant`